# Cant display table from JSON data using PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

Hay Guys , im new programming, i want to display my JSON data to html, but when I run, no data comes out on that table

MY Json

```
[
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 11,
      "Kode_Provi": 31,
      "Provinsi": "DKI Jakarta",
      "Kasus_Posi": 698,
      "Kasus_Semb": 48,
      "Kasus_Meni": 74
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 12,
      "Kode_Provi": 32,
      "Provinsi": "Jawa Barat",
      "Kasus_Posi": 180,
      "Kasus_Semb": 8,
      "Kasus_Meni": 20
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 16,
      "Kode_Provi": 36,
      "Provinsi": "Banten",
      "Kasus_Posi": 128,
      "Kasus_Semb": 1,
      "Kasus_Meni": 4
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 15,
      "Kode_Provi": 35,
      "Provinsi": "Jawa Timur",
      "Kasus_Posi": 91,
      "Kasus_Semb": 16,
      "Kasus_Meni": 8
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 13,
      "Kode_Provi": 33,
      "Provinsi": "Jawa Tengah",
      "Kasus_Posi": 81,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 7
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 27,
      "Kode_Provi": 73,
      "Provinsi": "Sulawesi Selatan",
      "Kasus_Posi": 50,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 17,
      "Kode_Provi": 51,
      "Provinsi": "Bali",
      "Kasus_Posi": 19,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 14,
      "Kode_Provi": 34,
      "Provinsi": "Daerah Istimewa Yogyakarta",
      "Kasus_Posi": 18,
      "Kasus_Semb": 1,
      "Kasus_Meni": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 23,
      "Kode_Provi": 64,
      "Provinsi": "Kalimantan Timur",
      "Kasus_Posi": 17,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 2,
      "Kode_Provi": 12,
      "Provinsi": "Sumatera Utara",
      "Kasus_Posi": 13,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 20,
      "Kode_Provi": 61,
      "Provinsi": "Kalimantan Barat",
      "Kasus_Posi": 9,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 33,
      "Kode_Provi": 94,
      "Provinsi": "Papua",
      "Kasus_Posi": 9,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 3,
      "Kode_Provi": 13,
      "Provinsi": "Sumatera Barat",
      "Kasus_Posi": 8,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 9,
      "Kode_Provi": 18,
      "Provinsi": "Lampung",
      "Kasus_Posi": 8,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 21,
      "Kode_Provi": 62,
      "Provinsi": "Kalimantan Tengah",
      "Kasus_Posi": 7,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 10,
      "Kode_Provi": 21,
      "Provinsi": "Kepulauan Riau",
      "Kasus_Posi": 6,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 1,
      "Kode_Provi": 11,
      "Provinsi": "Aceh",
      "Kasus_Posi": 5,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 22,
      "Kode_Provi": 63,
      "Provinsi": "Kalimantan Selatan",
      "Kasus_Posi": 5,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 4,
      "Kode_Provi": 14,
      "Provinsi": "Riau",
      "Kasus_Posi": 3,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 26,
      "Kode_Provi": 72,
      "Provinsi": "Sulawesi Tengah",
      "Kasus_Posi": 3,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 28,
      "Kode_Provi": 74,
      "Provinsi": "Sulawesi Tenggara",
      "Kasus_Posi": 3,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 5,
      "Kode_Provi": 15,
      "Provinsi": "Jambi",
      "Kasus_Posi": 2,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 6,
      "Kode_Provi": 16,
      "Provinsi": "Sumatera Selatan",
      "Kasus_Posi": 2,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 18,
      "Kode_Provi": 52,
      "Provinsi": "Nusa Tenggara Barat",
      "Kasus_Posi": 2,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 24,
      "Kode_Provi": 65,
      "Provinsi": "Kalimantan Utara",
      "Kasus_Posi": 2,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 25,
      "Kode_Provi": 71,
      "Provinsi": "Sulawesi Utara",
      "Kasus_Posi": 2,
      "Kasus_Semb": 1,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 34,
      "Kode_Provi": 91,
      "Provinsi": "Papua Barat",
      "Kasus_Posi": 2,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 8,
      "Kode_Provi": 19,
      "Provinsi": "Kepulauan Bangka Belitung",
      "Kasus_Posi": 1,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 30,
      "Kode_Provi": 76,
      "Provinsi": "Sulawesi Barat",
      "Kasus_Posi": 1,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 31,
      "Kode_Provi": 81,
      "Provinsi": "Maluku",
      "Kasus_Posi": 1,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 32,
      "Kode_Provi": 82,
      "Provinsi": "Maluku Utara",
      "Kasus_Posi": 1,
      "Kasus_Semb": 0,
      "Kasus_Meni": 0
    }
  }
]
```

My Code Req.php

```
require('rec.php'); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://URL'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$colek = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
$result=json_decode($colek,true); 
foreach ($result as $cocok) { 
    #var_dump($value); #die(); 
}
```

My Index.php

```
<?php               
    for($a=1; $a < count($cocok); $a++)
    {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>".$a."</td>";
        print "<td>".$cocok[$a]['Provinsi']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$cocok[$a]['Kasus_Posi']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$cocok[$a]['Kasus_Semb']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$cocok[$a]['Kasus_Meni']."</td>";
        print "</tr>";


    }
?>
```

I've tried a number of ways on google but haven't found a solution, please help.

Comment: In your index.php you are referencing the values in `$cocok`, whichis only ever referenced in your `foreach()`, have you tried using `$result` instead?

Comment: im using $cocok, because my code in rec.php

here is code 

`<?php

$ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api/');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $colek = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  //mengubah data json menjadi data array asosiatif
  $result=json_decode($colek,true);
   #var_dump($result);
#die();;
  //looping data menggunakan foreach
   foreach ($result['attributes'] as $cocok) {

  }

?>

`

Comment: It is not even clear what the connection between those two scripts is supposed to be. And `Req.php` appears to require _itself_, the way you have currently shown your code here? Doesn’t make sense, please show a _proper_ example of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you have a json like this :

```
[
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 11,
      "Kode_Provi": 31,
      "Provinsi": "DKI Jakarta",
      "Kasus_Posi": 698,
      "Kasus_Semb": 48,
      "Kasus_Meni": 74
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 12,
      "Kode_Provi": 32,
      "Provinsi": "Jawa Barat",
      "Kasus_Posi": 180,
      "Kasus_Semb": 8,
      "Kasus_Meni": 20
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "FID": 16,
      "Kode_Provi": 36,
      "Provinsi": "Banten",
      "Kasus_Posi": 128,
      "Kasus_Semb": 1,
      "Kasus_Meni": 4
    }
  }
]
```

You could modify the *Req.php* codes to make a `$cocok` array like this :

```php
require('rec.php'); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://URL'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$colek = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
$result=json_decode($colek,true); 
$cocok = [];
foreach ($result as $value) { // note the variable
    // var_dump($cocok); #die();
    $cocok[] = $value['attributes'];
}
```

Then you could use the `$cocok` variable just like what you have on *Index.php*.